# How to get an Instagram profile picture

Tags: android, android-studio, image-processing, instagram, instagram-api

In my app use, I want to put an Instagram profile picture in his/her account.

How can I get the profile picture of a user from Instagram *programmatically*?

Such as:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using the Instagram API users endpoint (`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`
) you will receive a response like this one:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}
```

You can then take the `profile_picture` and download it using some like [Facebook Fresco](https://code.facebook.com/projects/465232426958622/fresco/) which will then display the image for you.

Comment: The access token would be the token you are issued through the Instagram API. There are plenty of resources out there about what they are, you can find information about how Instagram grants tokens from their [developer resources](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Comment: I had registered in instagram developer site and get CLIENT ID not  access token

Comment: You use the client id to generate an access token. The developer resources link I provided tells how to accomplish that.

Comment: example or video  please

Comment: You can find examples by searching on Google, if you have additional questions about how to create an access token I'd suggest asking another question as this is now out of scope of your original answer.

Comment: @Kenji this answer was from nearly 2 years ago. The Instagram API has likely changed in that time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you actually want the user to [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) an Instagram profile picture from your app, you can't. Instagram hasn't provided the *POST method* for posting photos, but yes, you can get the view and download as per husky's answer.

Comment: As i said otherwise his answer should do. I see your problem is with the access token. Check this link on how to obtain it. [https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/]

Comment: now I get the access token but how get profile photo

Comment: There isn't anyone by the name "husky" here. What does it refer to?

Comment: OK, the OP might have [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get profile pic in your app

1. Make a request to below link with username and receive the `JSON` data.
   `https://apinsta.herokuapp.com/u/USERNAME`
2. Now parse the `id` of user from the data.
3. Now visit this link with the `ID`
   `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/ID_HERE/info/`
4. Now parse `url` key in `hd_profile_pic_url_info` object.
5. Load the image in `ImageView` using `Glide`.

**Happy coding !**

Credit to Chrisby for his server.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/49862390/9565955

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm using a method that doesn't require an access token. The only thing you need is a username. I'll leave you the code down below.

**Step 1: MainActivity.java**

1. Add this code in to your main activity. Create a String function named *getHDProfilePicFromUsername*. The function should look like this:

   ```
    /// This function will return to you the URL of the user profile picture
     private String getHDProfilePicFromUsername(String username) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JSONException {
         JSONObject jObject;
         String profileInfo = new getDataFromUrl(MainActivity.this).execute("https://www.instagram.com/"+username+"/?__a=1").get();

          jObject= new JSONObject(profileInfo);
          jObject  = jObject.getJSONObject("graphql");
          jObject  = jObject.getJSONObject("user");
          String response  = jObject.getString("profile_pic_url_hd");
          return response;
        }
   ```
2. Then create an internal class inside your Activity named getDataFromUrl. The class should look like this:

   ```
    private class getDataFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Context mContext;
        public getDataFromUrl(Context mContext) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(arg0[0]);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                return jsonStr;
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            String url = s.replace('|',',').split(",")[1];
            Log.d(TAG, "Link: " + url);
        }
    }
   ```

Now you are able to get a user profile picture URL. As a bonus, I'll let you with the code for using that URL and get the picture in to an ImageView.

**Step 2: main_activity.xml**

1. Add an image view, the ImageView. It can be custom, but I recommend a 1:1 scale to keep the image quality. Your XML content should look like this:

   ```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   ```

**Step 3: DownloadImageTask.java**

Now you need to create an external class called DownloadImageTask. The full code have to be like this one:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**Step 4: MainActivity.java**

Now the last step will be to add your Main Activity, the piece of code to load the ImageView. This code will be in your OnCreate void inside your *MainActivity.java* file:

```
ImageView = thumbnails = (ImageView)findItemById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
new DownloadImageTask(thumbnails).execute(getHDProfilePicFromUsername("jusnjshb"));
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working now. You may still use a similar link to view the user account json, but no longer be able to retrieve it via API call. Guess they put on some kind of CORS protection.

Comment: This is currently not working, cause of 2 thing: 1. Instagram upgraded their security you can only access data from that API if you are logged in to your Instagram account and 2. Async task has been deprecated (this one is fixable), you will need to find a work around the number 1