# How can I use the Instagram API to load an Instagram profile picture from a profile user URL?

Tags: oauth, load, instagram, picasso

I tried to display an image from a URL and so far I have succeeded, but it doesn't work when I'm trying to load an Instagram profile picture from a user's URL.
I would like to know how I can use the Instagram API to get the user's image and load it into an imageview using [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

I am using Java in Android Studio.

Comment: Related: *[How to get an Instagram profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494863/how-to-get-an-instagram-profile-picture)*. It *might* be a duplicate as there are two ***identical*** answers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm using a method that doesn't require an Access Token the only thing your need is an username. I'll leave you the code down bellow

**Step 1: MainActivity.java**

1. Add this code in to your main activity, create a String function to  named getHDProfilePicFromUsername and another fuction named getBetweenStrings those functions should look like this:

First getHDProfilePicFromUrl

```
    ///This function will return to you the url of the user profile picture
    private String getHDProfilePicFromUrl(String url) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JSONException {

        JSONObject jObject;
        String parsingUsername,username;
            if(url.contains("?"))
            {
                parsingUsername = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("?"))+"/";
            }
            else{
                parsingUsername = url;
            }
            username = getBetweenStrings(parsingUsername,".com/","/");
        String profileInfo = new getDataFromUrl(this).execute("https://www.instagram.com/"+username+"/?__a=1").get();

        jObject= new JSONObject(profileInfo);
        jObject  = jObject.getJSONObject("graphql");
        jObject  = jObject.getJSONObject("user");
        String response  = jObject.getString("profile_pic_url_hd");
        return response;     }
```

Second getBetweenStrings

```
private String getBetweenStrings( String text, String textFrom, String textTo) {
String result = "";
result = text.substring( text.indexOf(textFrom) + textFrom.length(), text.length());
result =  result.substring(0,result.indexOf(textTo));
return result;
}
```

2. Then create an internal class inside your Activity named getDataFromUrl, the class should look like this:

   ```
   private class getDataFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       Context mContext;
       public getDataFromUrl(Context mContext) {
           this.mContext = mContext;
       }
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();

       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
           HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

           // Making a request to url and getting response
           String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(arg0[0]);

           Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

           if (jsonStr != null) {
               return jsonStr;
           } else {
               Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
               return null;
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           super.onPostExecute(s);
           String url = s.replace('|',',').split(",")[1];
           Log.d(TAG, "Link: " + url);
       }
   }
   ```

Now you are able to get an user profile picture URL, as a bonus I'll let you the code for using that URL and get the picture in to an ImageView.

**Step 2: main_activity.xml**

1. Add an image view, the ImageView, can be custom but I recommend 1:1 scale to keep image quality. Your xml should look like this:

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
       android:layout_width="300dp"
       android:layout_height="300dp"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

**Step 3: DownloadImageTask.java**

Now you need to create an  external class called DownloadImageTask the full code have to be like this one:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**Step 4: MainActivity.java**

Now the last step will be to add your Main Activity the piece of code to load the ImageView, this code will be in your OnCreate void inside your MainActivity.java

```
String url="https://www.instagram.com/juanjshb/";
ImageView = thumbnails = (ImageView)findItemById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
new DownloadImageTask(thumbnails).execute(getHDProfilePicFromUrl(url));
```

That's all, hope it helps I have 2 years using this code hope it helps.