# How to get Instagram Profile Picture officially?

Tags: facebook, instagram

There are two answers here:

1. [How to get Instagram Profile Picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086945/how-to-get-instagram-profile-picture)

Using https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1 is working now but not official, it could be down any time without notice.

2. [how to get instagram profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494863/how-to-get-instagram-profile-picture)

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN is deprecated now and is not valid for review

The latest doc shows the way to get profile of business and creator only 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user

Is there any way to get name and profile image of normal user officially?

Comment: You need to be more specific, you have to say the core, device or at least the language you want to use

Comment: I am asking about the rest api, so no specific device, it could be web or mobile.

Comment: Did you found something ? I need the profile pic (big) of an account from its username... Some websites are doing it, but I don't find it in the api doc.

Comment: I finally used this one for that project https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1