# How to get an Instagram user's profile picture url?

Tags: instagram

I have an app that our employs Facebook Login and has our users connect their Instagram accounts via Instagram Basic Display API.

So I have an Instagram basic display access token for each of our user's and I have their 'account ids' but I cannot figure out how to get the user's profile picture through this API?

Comment: have you found the solution because i'm stuck at exact same point 
searching for solution to this same problme 
I got long term access token and userid, username.

How can i get other profile infomration like followers, bio, profile_pic ? 
Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 3):

If you could get the users `username` you could use this link as `GET` request: https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1

**Example** would be:

```
https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
```

Then you get the user information for the user `instagram`

You get source **URL** to the picture in `"profile_pic_url"`: & `"profile_pic_url_hd"` in the message `Body`  which is the **link** to the **profile photo**, hope it helps.

Comment: This works until Instagram rate limits your ip. After a number of calls I noticed my requests started failing. I suppose combined with a number of proxies this is an option if there really is no official api for it.

Comment: perhaps use the profile_pic_url then to find image via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media ? (not sure though if user's profile pic is also available as part of user's media and not just metadata)

Comment: TLDR is that it no longer works or it only works if you're logged in to the account. Follow this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265339/instagram-a-1-url-not-working-anymore-problems-with-graphql-query-to-get-da

Answer (score 0):

AS you have a user access-token that means you can have a user Instagram id.

```
GET graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{instagram-user-id}
response : {.....,
            has_profile_picture: bool type 
            profile_pic : url sting type
            ....
           }
```

The above API will help you and for more, you can follow the below link it has all the info required to get user details.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-user/

Comment: I've tried this. The token and user_id I have from my users logging in through the Basic Display API Display is not compatible with this graph API

Answer (score -1):

Have you integrated Instagram's Graph API?
Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

Comment: Yeah, and I'm using this api to fetch the user's instagram username. However these docs only specify 4 fields that can be queried; account_type, id, media_type, username.

There doesn't seem to be a profile_picture_url field, but it feels (and I'm hoping) like this should be accessible somewhere.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/41494968/4439983, might help you

Comment: Yeah I've read that. The issue there is the older techniques are outdated as instagram's api has changed a lot in the past couple years. The most recent solution is what I was doing but realized instagram rate limits requests so I'd have to dial in a proxy farm to route my requests through to not get blocked as were making a lot of requests. I've implemented a solution that does hit a user's profile picture, I just feel like theirs got to be a better more robust way but maybe not.